# SQL Server - Check column if exists >> rename and change type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**SQL Server:**

- Check column if exists when
- If True : (Change/Modify) column_name and dataType
- If False : Create

Schema name : Setup

Code:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns  
           WHERE Name = N'bitIntialBalance' 
             AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'Setup.LeaveVacationsSubType'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [Setup].[LeaveVacationsSubType] 
        ALTER COLUMN intIntialBalance INT NULL; 

    EXEC sp_RENAME 'Setup.LeaveVacationsSubType.bitIntialBalance', 'intIntialBalance', 'COLUMN';
    --ALTER TABLE [Setup].[LeaveVacationsSubType] MODIFY [intIntialBalance] INT; not working
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns  
              WHERE Name = N'intIntialBalance' 
                AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'Setup.LeaveVacationsSubType'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [Setup].[LeaveVacationsSubType] 
        ADD intIntialBalance INT NULL; 
END
GO
```

Comment: Do you have any problem?

Comment: where's the question?

Comment: this code not working

Answer (score 3):

If I guess correctly, the problem is that query plan is made for the whole script, and SQL Server also checks that it can actually perform all the operations, even if it is inside an if statement. That's why you'll get an error, even if in the reality that statement would never be executed.

One way to get around this issue is to make all those statements dynamic, something like this:

```
execute ('ALTER TABLE [Setup].[LeaveVacationsSubType] MODIFY [intIntialBalance] INT')
```